# CPT and metabox: create multi checkbox by using array?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, array

I have a custom post type to display informations of book. Then I created a metabox for it. And:

I need to add a warning system *(like: for kid, violent, mature, adult, etc...)* chosen by multi checkbox, then display them to the CPT by warning icons (png or svg)

How can I use array to create this options, save and display?

Here's my metabox addding:

```
global $st_series_cpt;
$prefix = 'st_series_';

$wpar_meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'series-post-meta-box',
    'title' => 'Information',
    'page' => 'stfic',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(???)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "fields" argument to [`add_meta_box()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), which I assume is what you are using and not some code-bloat-ie helper function/class nonsense. And you've not identified a callback, which is the key. Create a callback and put your "warning" array in that, along with code to create your checkboxe/radio-boxes, or whatever you need.

```
$wpar_meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'series-post-meta-box',
    'title' => 'Information',
    'callback' => 'st_meta_box',
    'page' => 'stfic',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
);
function st_meta_box($post) {
  $warn = array(
    'kid', 'violent', 'mature', 'adult'
  );
  // Code to create form markup
}
```